# Copy Data from REST API to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Do we need some additional permissions when we are writing the data from Rest API to a container that is behind a firewall ?

I can copy data easily to container without firewall but the data it fails writing to firewall container with the error :

> ErrorCode=HttpFileFailedToRead,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read data from http server. Check the error from http server：The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=System,'

Comment: What firewall settings does your container have?

Comment: From where you are writing the data into your storage account?

Comment: I am writing it from Rest API as a source , only selected IP addresses and Virtual network can access it

Comment: Does the IP address of the computer from where you are invoking the REST API included in Firewall settings of Azure Storage? Without that, your requests will be blocked.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for your response, this issue was happening on DB side as well. I was able to write to Azure SQL Db but not to synapse serverless pool , I was having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> I can copy data easily to container without firewall but the data it fails writing to firewall container with the error.

To load data in Container which is behind firewall Rules of storage account like `Private network access` are **Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses**.

1. You need to crate Managed private endpoints for that particular blob storage in ADF.

**Manage >> Managed private endpoints >> New >>Azure Blob Storage/ Azure ADLS gen2 storage >> Continue.**

Provide Your subscription and Storage account name and click on `create`.

[image]

2. Approve this end points from your storage account by

**Networking >> Private endpoint connections >> select endpoint requested by data factory >> Approve.**

[image]

3. Create Azure Integration runtime with **Virtual network >> virtual network configuration as Enabled**

[image]

4. Now with this Integration runtime create Linked service for particular storage account and run the pipeline.

[image]

**Successfully able to copy data from Rest API to a container that is behind a firewall.**

[image]

Reference: [Managed private endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint)